# Convert a wired headset to a wireless one

Tags: usb, audio, wireless, bluetooth, hacking

new to the board and not caught up with current technology, but I can handle myself when it comes to soldering and small electrical appliances. I have a headset that I really love, but the wire snagged on something and snapped. I could wire the headset back together, but I thought I'd do something a bit cooler. I'd like to fit a wireless transmitter as well as a cell phone battery inside the headset to convert it into a wireless headset. The battery is already installed and working, and now I have a bit of a puzzle in front of me:

Do I solder the remaining points back into USB female port, then stick that into the headset and use an out-of-the-box wireless USB data transmitter / USB Bluetooth transmitter? Or is there a compact wireless board I can easily use to send the audio data? The soldering points I'm dealing with seem to be left speaker, right speaker, and a data point. I've tried looking for wireless USB data transfer kits, but the ones I can find are bulky. On the other hand, I can't find a Bluetooth setup out of the box because any USB plugins for Bluetooth seem to assume the port you are plugging into should be broadcasting audio, not receiving it. Suggestions welcome, pictures and a walkthrough if I am successful.

EDIT: I found a Bluetooth SMD Module on sparkfun.com, I think it can do what I need it to: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11678
My only question is, is this a solder and go or do I need to make my own drivers for it?

EDIT 2: Hacked a Bluetooth headset and wired it all up, works great. I wasn't confident I'd be able to use the breakout board for the module I linked without writing my own drivers, so now my Razer Banshees are recognized as a Verizon headset, but the sound quality is good and I had the spare cell phone batteries. If anyone can give me insight on using breakout boards in the future I'd be grateful.

Comment: Congrats. So you're new question is actually how to use breakout boards?

Comment: Yeah, I guess it is. Are they solder and go solutions, or do I need to write drivers for them? I'd love to be able to wire in a power source and then simply solder on a few wires to the breakout board, then presto change-o, but I didn't think it would be that easy.

Comment: It's not that easy, but popular break out boards have always some drivers for them available online, especially when using arduino